# How to convert C style cast to C++ style cast in vim

Tags: c++, vim

I got hand over some legacy code and first I want to change

```
(int)a + b;
```

into

```
static_cast<int>(a) + b;
```

There are a lot of them and doing them manually is very time consuming. Is there a way to use vim to make this happen?

I tried something like

```
:%s/\(int\).* /static_cast<int>(\2)/g
```

but it doesn't work. Please advice.

Comment: I would convert the pointer casts to named C++ casts, for correctness, but these considerations don't apply to the number type casts, which I'd just leave in place or possibly convert to C++ notation `int(a)` (which means the same). I.e., don't introduce *unnecessary new verbosity*.

Comment: You would probably get better results using something like [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/google-readability-casting.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/(\(.*\))\([^ ]*\)/static_cast<\1>(\2)/g
```

This regex, as per your question, assumes that there will be a space after the variable name:

**Example:**
For following test data:

```
(int)a + b
(float)x * y
(int)z+m
```

result will be

```
static_cast<int>(a) + b
static_cast<float>(x) * y
static_cast<int>(z+m)
```

**Explaining the regex**

`(\(.*\))` - Match whatever is inside `()` and capture it
`\([^ ]*\)` - followed by anything which is not a space and capture it

Comment: It might be a bit too flexible since anything in the brackets that are not meant as C style cast will be changed as well, but it works!

Comment: If I understand the regex correctly, the `[^ ]` (not space) bit is the part which determines the terms which go inside the cast. That's essentially a parse problem, of unbound complexity - a regex never can solve it. `(int)(p + q)` is parsed to `static_cast<int>((p) + q)`. OTOH, it's fairly obvious that `z+m` would have been better parsed if we had used `[^ +-*/%^&|?]`. No quick solution for `(int) arr[i]`

Comment: @user3667089 : True, the regex is pretty simplistic. But can be easily expanded to only match some of the basic data types by changing the regex to this `:%s/(\(int\|float\|double\))\([^ ]*\)/static_cast<\1>(\2)/g` . But glad it helped you in it's current form too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
%s/(int)\(a\)/static_cast<int>(\1)/g
```

This is assuming variable name always is `a`. If it is not then you can replace `a` with `[a-z]`.

Comment: The problem is that you cast expressions, not variables. There's no regular expression which can capture all expressions and only expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have several mappings for this task in [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp).

In that case, it'll be `,,sc`, or `,,rc`, or `,,dc`. (here, `,` is actually my `<localleader>`).

It's actually implemented as:

```
function! s:ConvertToCPPCast(cast_type)
  " Extract text to convert
  let save_a = @a
  normal! gv"ay
  " Strip the possible brackets around the expression
  let expr = matchstr(@a, '^(.\{-})\zs.*$')
  let expr = substitute(expr, '^(\(.*\))$', '\1', '')
  "
  " Build the C++-casting from the C casting
  let new_cast = substitute(@a, '(\(.\{-}\)).*',
    \ a:cast_type.'<\1>('.escape(expr, '\&').')', '')
  " Do the replacement
  exe "normal! gvs".new_cast."\<esc>"
  let @a = save_a
endfunction

vnoremap <buffer> <LocalLeader><LocalLeader>dc
    \ <c-\><c-n>:'<,'>call <sid>ConvertToCPPCast('dynamic_cast')<cr>
    nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader><LocalLeader>dc viw<LocalLeader><LocalLeader>dc

...
```